# How to create axes for a console controller

Tags: unity, c#, input, controllers, joystick

What should I change in the input manager to enable me to use a joystick? I have a usb cable to connect the joystick to the computer but how do I set up the controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up new axes for joysticks in the input manager by using "Joystick Axis" for the Type. The left stick would need two entries in the input manager, one horizontal (using the X axis), and one vertical (using the Y axis). The right joystick , using the 3rd and 4th axes. To use this in scripting, you need to get through Input.GetAxis("Joystick Left"), where "Joystick Left" is the name of the axis created in the input manager.

[image]

Unity already has some predefined joystick settings , you can try if those work for you, else you can make new axes as per your need.